# how can I use a DLL that reades from web.config in .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dll, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a DLL that I use for: Asp.net website & WinForms, I have problems using it in
**.Net Core 3.1**
the DLL is reading data from the web.config
for example:

```
apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyApiKey"];
```

When I try running it using .Net Core I get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.'

When I Install the NuGet **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager**

I get this Error:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration
>   system failed to initialize' ConfigurationErrorsException:
>   Unrecognized configuration section system.serviceModel.
>   (P:\Projects\MyProjectName\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyDllName.dll.config
>   line 48)

In line 48 I Have this Soap Bindings:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyTestServiceSoap">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="MyTestServiceSoap1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://ws.MyTest.com/ws/test/service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyTestServiceSoap" contract="MyTestServiceSoap.MyTestServiceSoap" name="MyTestServiceSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The Problem Is that I also have to change this setting (line 48)  So that the DLL will work OK.
Please note that I have different settings for Debug & Release.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core applications to communicate with WCF services you need to install `System.ServiceModel.Primitives` through NuGet.

Install that first and see if that works. You might also need to NuGet install `System.ServiceModel.Http`

Here is the github page

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf

Comment: Thank for you answer , but you didn't give me solution to read this info from the web.config, as I wrote it doesn't read line 48 .... and I need to read this data

Comment: @DoronAviad It is weird having to manually read the WCF endpoints configuration, usually when you are working with WFC you pass the desired endpoint name when calling the client constructor and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

After Checking the web **there is no way to use legacy DLL** with .Net Core 3.1

> The DLL must be DOTNETSTANDART 2.0 to work

There is no support for legacy libs like Linq2SQL.

So I have to build a new DLL in 2.0 in order to use it with .Net Core 3.1
there is a way to use the 2.0 DLL in .Net Framework 4.6 and up